# Excluding undefined Field Values in MariaDB TypeORM Queries

Tags: sql, nestjs, typeorm

I have a basic [Nest](https://docs.nestjs.com/) project using [TypeORM](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database). A model, `Plate`, has been contained in its own module and is imported into the main module.

The service for the Plate model contains the following method:

```js
public query(params?: QueryPlateParams, limit: number = 100): Promise<Plate[]> {

    const findOp = PlatesService.FindOperatorMap[params.type];

    const whereObj = {
        // If a find operation is defined, apply it to the value. Otherwise, just use the
        // value itself.
        id: findOp?.(params.value) ?? params.value,
        available: params.isAvailable,
        state: params.state
    };
    console.log(whereObj);

    return this._platesRepository.find({
        where: whereObj,
        take: limit
    });
}
```

The idea of this method is to take the query object, which could have any combination of the `value`, `isAvailable`, and `state` properties defined, then to apply the defined values to the query's `WHERE` clause with some modification, of course not defining filters for fields which had no value in the source query object.

When a query is made, the following logs are observed.

```
{ id: 'ABSOLVE', available: undefined, state: undefined }
query: SELECT `Plate`.`id` AS `Plate_id`, `Plate`.`state` AS `Plate_state`, `Plate`.`available` AS `Plate_available`, `Plate`.`lastChecked` AS `Plate_lastChecked` FROM `plates` `Plate` WHERE (`Plate`.`id` = ? AND `Plate`.`available` = ? AND `Plate`.`state` = ?) LIMIT 100 -- PARAMETERS: ["ABSOLVE",null,null]
```

What's important here is the parameter interpolation at the end of the second line: `PARAMETERS: ["ABSOLVE",null,null]`. The values for `isAvailable` and `state` are `undefined`, but the SQL statement translated them to `null`, but `undefined` and `null` are distinct values in Javascript/Typescript. The intent, of course, is to *ignore* `undefined` values in the query, not interpret them as `null`.

I found an [option](https://typeorm.delightful.studio/interfaces/_driver_mongodb_mongoconnectionoptions_.mongoconnectionoptions.html#ignoreundefined) for the *MongoDB* connector that will ignore these `undefined` values. I do not see the same for the MariaDB/MySQL connector, which is what is being used for this service.

Is there any option to ignore these `undefined` values instead of interpreting them as `null`? I'd like to use the [`IsNull()`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/find-options/operator/IsNull.ts) or `null` values to explicitly check for SQL `NULL`.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly you need just to not provide the undefined fields (add filter before passing `whereObj` into the find function.

Or you can read this thread with some other options dealing with the issue https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2934

Basically - the issue is because creator thought that setting property of object to `undefined` removes the property from the object own properties therefore he treated undefined and null the same.

Comment: What a shame. Thanks for linking the issue. I agree with those in the thread that state an option to control this behavior would solve the issue for everyone and wouldn't be that hard to implement. I was hoping to avoid omitting `undefined` values in every TypeORM query.

Comment: There is a reason why im using Sequelize (and thats one of them)

Comment: My application was originally using Sequelize, but I liked the way TypeORM looked. I'll have to investigate the pros and cons of going back to Sequelize. The reason I created this question is because I was used to this sort of behavior in Sequelize, but was not seeing it in TypeORM.